# Fail to check jxbrowser license

Tags: licensing, jxbrowser

I have a free evaluation license of JXBrowser and have been following the instructions for IntelliJ (https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012869-jxbrowser-in-intellij-idea) to get the HelloWorld example up and running:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserCore;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.Environment;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.BrowserView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        // On Mac OS X Chromium engine must be initialized in non-UI thread.
        if (Environment.isMac()) {
            BrowserCore.initialize();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(browserView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JxBrowser: JavaFX - Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        browser.loadHTML("<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

All jxbrowser stuff and the license.jar are added to the projects dependencies but I still get

```
Exception in Application init method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in    Application init method
    at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:912)
    at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.getDefault(SourceFile:44)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserCore.initialize(SourceFile:51)
    at JXBrowserApp.init(JXBrowserApp.java:15)
    at         com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:841)
... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JxBrowser license check failed: No valid license found.
```

I'm using OS X El Capitan version 10.11.4 and IntelliJ version 2016.1.3 and java 8u101.

Anyone who knows what the problem might be or how to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the reason is that this free JxBrowser 30-days evaluation license has been expired.

Comment: Unfortunately that was not the issue since I got the license the same day I tried it out.

Comment: The evaluation license can be used only once and it works 30 days. If you download second evaluation license, it will not work. If you download the evaluation license for the first time, then please make sure that you include the license JAR file into application class path and you didn't modify the license file.

Comment: It might have been that I downloaded a second evaluation license. Thanks for your help Vladimir.

Comment: So if you download it twice, neither license file will work?

Comment: it appears so, I have two downloaded `license.jar` that are identical and neither works.  Both were issued a week ago and should not have expired.  You should just block the 2nd download because nothing makes it clear that you invalidate your license by downloading it twice.

Comment: Your test code has `<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>`. This is a problem. Create a `Maven` project using something from `https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/`. From there, add `JXBrowser` using `Maven`. Use their example to construct your `Main`. That's my guess.

Comment: Also, note that `JxBrowser` is probabaly not modular.

Answer (score 0):

`license.jar` is for the older versions of JX Browser **(version 6)**. For **version 7.1**, `license.jar` is not used. Instead, the license key will be inserted in the code itself:

```
Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(EngineOptions.newBuilder(RenderingMode.OFF_SCREEN)
    .licenseKey("1BNDHFSC1FTA7A76VKWRRM8IRYEAL48AT20PIS26JQO0CK3H6Y0P58QPVB084Y1K4IU98T").build());
```